# Applications headbar is acting weird and changing color

Tags: pulseaudio, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

Recently a few of my applications got their top bars acting weird. I thought that it only happened to my terminal, but turned out there were more. GNOME Terminal, LibreOffice, Task Manager, and PulseAudio aldo got affected. Screenshots can be found here: `https://postimg.cc/gallery/GvGvjfC`. Note that for some reasons, the taskbar is looking differently while unfocused.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not know what caused this, but recently I configured my polybar and changed the shell theme.

Comment: Is it resolved if you revert back to the default themes? What theme did you install?

Comment: @popey no, reverting back didn't help. I've installed kanagawa theme ``https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1810560/``

Comment: could these applications be affected because I've placed new theme file into ``~/.config/gtk-4.0``?